# Azure Data Factory - Retrieve next pagination link (decoded) from response headers in a copy data activity of Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, pagination, azure-data-factory, data-pipeline

I have created a copy data activity in azure data factory and this data pipeline pulls the data from an API (via REST activity source) and writes the response body (json) on a file kept in the azure blob storage.
The API which I am fetching the response from, is paginated and the link to next page is sent in the response headers in response->headers->link.

This URL to next page is in the following general format:
<https%3A%2F%2FsomeAPI.com%2Fv2%2FgetRequest%3FperPage%3D80%26sortOrder%3DDESCENDING%26nextPageToken%3DVAdjkjklfjjgkl>; rel="next"

I want to fetch the next page token present in the above URL and use it in the pagination rule.

I have tried using some pagination rules:

**> AbsoluteURL = Headers.link**
But, this did not work as the entire encoded link shown above, is getting appended directly and hence, the pipeline throws an error.

**> Query Parameters**
I have also tried to use the query parameters but could not get any result.

I have followed questions over stackoverflow and have read the documentations:

Please help me with how can I access this next page token or what can be the pagination rule to support the scenario.

Pasting postman output and ADF data pipeline, for reference.
[Postman Response Headers Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHjhJ.png)
[Pagination Rules, I need help on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpr2a.png)

Comment: [Referred the official documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support) I have tried following this official documentation but couldn't get success

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have a similar issue with an API that uses RFC5998.  I have it configured per the documentation (example 7), however, pagnation is not working.

Comment: @Josh No, so RFC5998 did not work for me. Probably, because the link which I am using is encoded. For now, I am doing the entire pipeline in python rather than using Azure Data Factory. The support for such small issues is not clearly found in the Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no direct option to decode the URL in ADF paginating rule.

You can follow below approach:

- First take a set variable and create `temp` variable as **string** and value as `1`
  [image]
- Then take until activity and give the condition as `@equals(variables('temp1'),10)` so it will iterate over it till condition matches.
  [image]
- Under the until loop take another set variable and create variable `URL1` as **string** and value as URL of rest api.
  [image]
- After this pass variable value to copy activity and copy the first page to destination.
  [image]
- After this take web activity and pass that URL variable to it and get response headers.
  [image]
- After this take set variable and update the URL to next page url usnig dynamic expression.

```
@uriComponentToString(split(split(activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders["link"],'>')[0],'<')[1])
```

[image]

- In last create a variable called increment as string and increment initial temp variable for every iteration by `@add(int(variables('temp1')),1)`
  [image]

By this process you can copy as many pages as you want or you set in Until loop as we don't have any specific condition to terminate loop.